# Can't open or execute command in cmd using java servlet

Tags: java, file

Want to execute echot.BAT file using java servlet. i have used following code.

```
Process croppingProcess =  Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("C:Windows/system32/cmd /c echot.BAT", null, new File("C:restapi_bat/echot"));
                int processOutput = croppingProcess.waitFor();
                if(processOutput == 0){
                    success = true;
            //do your work here
        }
```

but getting the error

> "C:Windows/system32/cmd" (in directory "C:restapi_bat\echot"):
>   CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid

file echot.BAT in  C:\restapi_bat
Note: using tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using escape and Start, bat executed the solution as follow

```
Process croppingProcess =  Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C Start C:\\restapi_bat\\echot ");
                int processOutput = croppingProcess.waitFor();
                if(processOutput == 0){
                    success = true;
            //do your work here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using C:Windows/system32/cmd you should use C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd, because  Windows separates with \. The / Separator is in Linux. And you have to Escape the \, so use \\.

Comment: This isn't needed; the Windows _API_ accepts either `/` or `\ `, it is only the user interfaces (CMD, explorer/filedialog/etc, and many utilities) that insist on the latter. But you do need the root marker just after the drive: `"C:/windows/system32/cmd"`